# What is the difference between <> and <?> in Java generic types?

Tags: java, generics, generic-list, generic-collections

When you create a collection field that takes a generic type you can do that by giving it ? as the value or nothing at all what is the difference between those:

e.g.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<?>();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement is just wrong; you cannot instantiate a parameterized class with an unknown type. You are likely confusing it with a similar syntax where the unknown is on a declared type as in this dummy example:

```
public static String getClassName(Class<?> clazz) {
   return clazz.getName();
}
```

In the example above, the use of <?> indicates that any type instantiation may be provided.

The last two statements are equivalent; in `new ArrayList<>()`, the `String` type parameter is inferred by the compiler from the declared type on the left-hand side, while in the last statement this is given explicitly. As others have correctly noted, this type inference is only available as of Java 7. Prior to Java 7, you can achieve similar type inference by taking advantage of the way that types are inferred on method invocations; for example, Guava's [Lists.newArrayList()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList()) allows one to write "Lists.newArrayList()" on the right-hand side without specifying the type a second time, and pre-JDK7 compilers will properly infer the type from the left-hand side there.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is a new feature introduces with Java 1.7. The empty generic bracers implicitly take the Generic Type of the left side. So basicly it is the same as your last example.

Additionaly your first example is worng (as the others already stated). Valid would be

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: @montss, it's still wrong since you would need a type on the right-hand side in this case.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan `List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();` will compile.

Comment: The JDK 1.7_51 gives no error on it, I think you meant logical error? any way those are just examples to make the question clearer, I think the guys understand the question and already gave the answer thanks.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, thanks for pointing that out. I meant that it was an error, but it turns out that I'm mistaken (I guess it infers "Object" in this case?). I believe it is still poor coding style, though, in that an explicit type was not given on neither the left-hand nor right-hand side (an explicit type should always be given somewhere at the point of instantiation).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Yes, it should be `Object`. I tried to go through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) to figure out why, but gave up 10 seconds in.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

is equivalent to

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Operator `<>` is called `diamond` and was introduced in JDK7

The first statement in your question is invalid.

Comment: `?` means more or less anything

Answer (score 0):

the first line is a [wild card](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) and the last two are short-code introduced with java 7 and they are the same [oracle source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)